# SQLAlchemy sqlite3.operational error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am developing flask project on my remote ubuntu server.I also use `SQLAlchemy`. However, when I try to run this script, I am getting the `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file` error.

This is my `models.py`

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'


    name =Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(String(250))

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id': self.id,
           'name': self.name,
           'description' : self.description
       }

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I followed Udacity fullstack web foundations tutorial and it worked on my local machine. However, I could not handle it on the server

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @Layne Nope.Couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Path probably is not resolving correctly. Try:

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'puppies.db')

Base = declarative_base()

class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'


    name =Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(String(250))

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id': self.id,
           'name': self.name,
           'description' : self.description
       }

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + DATABASE_PATH)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```